# Extract text from children of next nodes with XPath and Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

With Python Scrapy, I am trying to get contents in a webpage whose nodes look like this:

```
<div id="title">Title</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>blahblah</span>
    <div>blahblah</div>
    <p>CONTENT TO EXTRACT</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>blahblah</span>
    <div>blahblah</div>
    <p>CONTENT TO EXTRACT</p>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

I'm a newbie with XPath and couldn't get it for now. My last try was something like:

```
contents = response.xpath('[@id="title"]/following-sibling::ul[1]//li//p.text()')
```

... but it seems I cannot use `/following-sibling` after `[@id="title"]`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One XPath would be:

```py
response.xpath('//*[@id="title"]/following-sibling::ul[1]//p/text()).getall()
```

which get text from every `<p>` tag child or grand child of nearest `<ul>` tag to node with `id = "title"`.

[XPath syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this XPath

```
contents = response.xpath('//div[@id="title"]/following-sibling::ul[1]/li/p/text()')
```

It selects both "CONTENT TO EXTRACT" text nodes.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using css selector.

`response.css('#title ::text).extract()`